# Swiper Slider (Swiper 7.4.1) is "sometimes" showing second slide instead of first one

Tags: javascript, shopify, swiper.js

We have included a Slider with the Swiper 7.4.1 library in a shopify website. Here the Initialization code:

```
const slider = new Swiper('.text-swiper-{{ section.id }}-images', {
        direction: 'horizontal',
        loop: false,
        initialSlide: 0,
        observer: false,
        scrollbar: false,
        keyboard: true,
        mousewheel: true,
        navigation: true,
        pagination: false,
        slidesPerView: "auto",
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.text-slider-next-{{ section.id }}',
            prevEl: '.text-slider-prev-{{ section.id }}',
        },
    });
```

After loading the page, the slider starts at the second slide (index:1) instead of the first slide (index:0). The Navigation buttons although work correctly. Meaning the "return"-button is disabled and if you click on the "next"-button the current slide (index:1) stays and you can control the slider as expected.

[Second Slide showing after loading page, with navigation working like on first slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSvbS.jpg)

The weird thing is, that this only happens 50% of the time. If you reload the page it's really a coinflip if the first or the second slide appears.

I hope I could describe my problem understandably.
Thank you

--

I couldn't find/solve the problem. What I did now is just setting the transfrom attribute of the swiper-wrapper to translate3d(0, 0, 0) after the swiper loaded. Not really happy with it

Comment: Is first slide still scrollable? Is it present in slider? Did you try to update swiper to latest version?

Comment: I set scrollable to false, so it's not scrollable. If I click on the "next" button, the slide stays the same, but the "prevoius" button gets enabled. Afterwards it works just fine.
It's like the slider start on the correct slide (index: 0), but it shows the second one.
If I check the dev tools, the visible slide also has the class "swiper-slide-next", and the slider-wrapper element gets following style:

transform: translate3d(-889px, 0px, 0px);

Comment: Is there any javascript that affects overall swiper structure? For example calculates width of slides or any content inside of the slides? I feel it is something related to loading time of other code that affects your swiper, that can be only explanation why it works from time to time correct.

Comment: There is no code that calculates widths or maipulates the content. Maybe an other library is making problems. The library is working on several other pages on the same website without problems.

Comment: You have slidesPerView: 'auto', it means that width of slides is calculated depending on comtent. Maybe there are some images that load after swiper was created?

Comment: I tried setting the sliderPerView to 1, but that didn't do anything. The images might load afterwards, that I'm not so sure about.